# Why no Task is being created?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

While testing a few implementation option I have stumbled on some unclear issues regarding TPL. 
Basically my question is, When calling an async Task returning method, is a Task created? In the following code, what will happen?

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    Task t = SomeAsyncMethod()
    Task.WaitAll(t)  
}

private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SomeAsyncMethod()
{
        //some implementation
}
```

I assumed a Task should be created in this code but when watching the Parallel Task Debug window no Task was created. Would you please clarify this.

Update:
svick gave a good explanation to the above scenario, which created a follow up question.
Will the following code create two Task or only one? Is it good practice, when the main goal is to create separate Tasks.:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeAsyncMethodWrapper());
}

private async void SomeAsyncMethodWrappe(){
    ver result = await AsyncMethod();
    //do something with the result
}

private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>>(){
    //do some work and return a result value
    var innerResult = await someLibraryAsyncMethod();
    return innerResult;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`, as I [explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). To answer your followup question: your code as-is will create one code-based task and one event-based task. The code-based task is short-lived (i.e., it does not execute the code after the first `await` yields).

Comment: @StephenCleary, Great blog! can you please elaborate on code based tasks vs. event based task? Links will also do the work

Comment: Stephen Toub has some older but still relevant blog posts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/03/9691796.aspx), and I have one [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/creating-tasks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Task` will be created, otherwise your code couldn't work. But it's a different kind of `Task` from the ones that are used for parallel processing, which I assume is what “Parallel Tasks” means.

The difference is that “normal” `Task`s are basically wrappers around some synchronous code that usually executes on the `ThreadPool`. On the other hand, async `Task`s complete when something happens (some information is read from the disk; `async` method completes), but they don't directly represent some code and are never associated with a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Method should be like this if you want to see task in Parallel Tasks window.

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SomeAsyncMethod()
{
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));
return new List<string>();
}
```